# Python on Matlab. Cant import specific library

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to run a python script within MATLAB. I am using command `system("python train.py")`. Within the script I import h5py library. If I run the script from CMD everything works perfect. When I run it within MATLAB I get the following error.

```
system('C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python train.py');
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "train.py", line 3, in <module> 
    import h5py 
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 36, in <module> 
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters 
  File "h5py\h5r.pxd", line 21, in init h5py._conv 
  File "h5py\_objects.pxd", line 12, in init h5py.h5r 
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 1, in init h5py._objects 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

any suggestiongs?

Comment: Not sure if this is the same, but MATLAB uses a very old h5 library, and I have had big problems having code that works both in python and MATLAB and relies on h5.

Comment: To me this looks like a problem with the PATH environment variable. MATLAB likes to change it so it can find its own libraries. When h5py tries to open the h5 library, it opens MATLAB's copy instead of its own. As @Ander said, MATLAB's is older and might not contain all symbols that h5py expects in that library.